# "Uncaught HierarchyRequestError : new line tag after createTextNode

Tags: javascript

This is the code that I'm trying to make work:

```
var aform = document.createElement("form");
var model = document.createTextNode("xyz");
var newLine = document.createElement('br');
model.appendChild(newLine);
var status = document.createTextNode("abc");

aform.appendChild(model);
aform.appendChild(status);

$("#someDiv").append(aform);
```

when I try to run the code it keeps giving me error

> "Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method."

Can someone please suggest as to why is it not working? I just want a new line after creating text node xyz and then abc.

Comment: You can't append nodes to a text node.

Comment: @Pointy so how do I add a new line after model? I would like to emulate a html form . Thank you.

Comment: Append the first text node, append the `<br>`, then append the second text node.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, it'd be far easier to just use that library to do all this.

Comment: more specific please.. I don't understand. Do you mean something like model.append('<br />').. because that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var model = document.createTextNode("xyz");
var newLine = document.createElement('br');
model.appendChild(newLine);
```

You can't do that, because your parent is TEXT Node, this type of Node can't have childNodes.

```
var model = document.createTextNode("xyz");
```

is the same as:

```
var model.textContent = "xyz";
```

I recommend you to use innerHTML method, it work's in tens times faster, without jQuery, for example:

```
document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = "<form>xyz<br>abc</form>".
```

Or your code(fixed):

```
var aform = document.createElement("form");
        var model = document.createTextNode("xyz");
        var newLine = document.createElement('br');
        var status = document.createTextNode("abc");

        aform.appendChild(model);
        aform.appendChild(newLine);
        aform.appendChild(status);

        $("#someDiv").append(aform);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole thing with jQuery, since you're using it anyway:

```
$("#someDiv").append("<form>xyz<br>abc</form>");
```

Comment: this is a good method but I think it would be too cumbersome if I was to create a long form with all the usual options like submit, action etc. Not the best solution for me, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3044240 you should include all your conditions in your question so that people can provide useful answers. But in any case, you're using jQuery anyway, so you might as well use it. If you're building up a big form, you'd be far better off using a templating system.